# navbar background image not transparent

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an image which is essential a square with a semi-circular bottom. The image has a transparent background I want to set it as the repeating background of my navbar which gives the effect of a canopy.

I see that the transparent parts of the image are not transparent when i view my site, they are white.Why can i not see my sites background?

background image with transparent background[image]

Resulting nav bar
[image]

css

```
  .navbar-default {
        box-shadow: none;
        border: 0;
        margin-bottom:0; 
        background-image: url('../img/navbarbackground.png');
        font-family: angsannaUPC;
    }
```

html
     
    
        
          
              
                
                
                  
                    Toggle navigation
                    
                    
                    
                  
                  
                  M.F.O'Hare & Associates</a>-->

```
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li><a href="/projects.html">Cakes</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services.html">Buns</a></li>
                <li><a href="/aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the CSS

Comment: What type of image is it? JPEG, PNG, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the background of your navbar is not transparent.  The image may be transparent, but at least one of the layers behind it, the navbar div, or the fluid container, is not.

Comment: do you know how i can make it transparent?

Comment: background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);

Comment: I was about to say, in the css set navbar background-color to...  never mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got answer thx to Gilchrist. The navbar's background was not transparent. Adding this to css solved the issue.

```
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
```